# How do I add a print statement at the end of the default move constructor in c++11?

Tags: c++, move-constructor

I am interested in logging the invocation of a move constructor. However unlike copy constructor, where the presence of the member variables implies they will be default constructed, if I don't do anything in the body of the move constructor, nothing will be moved presumably. The convenient shorthand is usually to write `MyClass(MyClass&& c) = default`. But how do I add another statement after the default move construction?

Comment: See "Rule-of-Five" in [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: So you are OK that in an empty copy constructor nothing will be copied, but not OK that in an empty move constructor nothing will be moved? I'm not sure why you draw this distinction. In an empty user-defined move constructor, member variables will be default-constructed - exactly the same way as they would in a similar copy constructor.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You are right. I guess it’s not just move but also copy that I am asking about.

Comment: How about creating an empty class with a logging move constructor, then adding this class as a member of the class whose move-construction you wish to log?